# Is $s necessary when implementing a function that swaps while looping through a loop in MIPS?

Tags: mips, cpu-registers, preserve

```c
void sort (int v[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0;  i<n; i+=1){
        for(j=i-1; j>=0; && v[j]>v[j+1]; j-=1){
            swap(v,j);
            }
        }
    }
    
void swap(int v[], int k)
    {
        int temp;
        temp = v[k+1];
        v[k+1]= temp;
    }
```

below is MIPS code of swap function

```
swap : sll $t1, $a0, 2   // reg $t = k*4 
       add $t1, $a0, $t1 // reg $t1 = v+(k*4)
                         // reg $t1 has the address of v[k]
       lw  $t0, 0($t1)   // reg $t0 (temp) =v[k]
       lw  $t2, 4($t1)   // reg $t2 = v[k+1]
                         // refers to next element of v
       sw  $t2, 0($t1)   // v[k] = reg $t2
       sw  $t0, 4($t1)   // v[k+1] = reg $t0 (temp)
     
       jr  $ra           // return to calling routine
```

I am studying computer architecture. Through several procedures, we learned that values ​​that should not be changed are stored using a stack pointer or stored in `$S`.

However, in the code above, the parameters `v[]` (`$a0`) and `n`(`$a1`) of the sort function are stored in `$s0` `$s1` using the stack pointer, and before running the innermost loop, `$s0` in `$a0`, The data is shown as assigning the value of $s1 to `$a1`.

However, in the code above, `v[]` has to keep the changed state inside the swap function, and `j` also has to change the value while looping, so there is no need to save and put the previous value.

Is my explanation correct? That is, when implementing the above code in **MIPS**, there is no problem in using the stack pointer to not store it in `$s`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is $s necessary when implementing a function that swaps while looping through a loop in MIPS?

The `$s` registers are never necessary.  What is necessary is that the variable values of `v`, `n`, `i`, and `j` survive the function call to `swap`.  There are two ways to make values survive the function call, and one is to use (stack) memory and the other is to use `$s` registers, so,  `$s` register are not strictly necessary at all.  (Both forms involve stack memory (and the same amount, as well), but the former uses the stack memory directly for the variable values, and the latter uses the stack memory in preservation of the `$s` registers' original values).

However, `$s` registers are preferred for variables that have multiple uses, (measured dynamically by instruction execution at runtime rather than statically as seen in code listing) and where also such variable must survive a function call.  (Of course, arrays cannot live in `$s` registers, but a reference to the array (a pointer variable) can.)

Why do these variables have to survive the function call?  Because they are each consumed (used, sourced) after the call, though having been defined (set, targeted) before the function call.  Programs expect continuity of their variables whether or not function calls happen.

Let's call out the difference between logical variables used by high level language and pseudo code vs. the physical storage of machine code.

Logical variables have names, types, scope/lifetime (they come and go, some frequently during program execution, as local variables and parameters).  There is an infinite number of possible ones — just create a new name as we like (and can also be unnamed, as with heap data structures).  A program using logical variables has an expectation of continuity — that once set, a variable retains its value until changed by the program (and then retains that new value).

The physical storage of the machine is permanent and global and just groups of bits.  The CPU registers are always present, as is memory (let's gloss over virtualization).  The CPU does not see variables, their declarations, their names, their types or their lifetimes — the CPU sees physical storage.  (How does it work then?  The CPU is told, via machine instructions, how to interact with physical storage; it is so told as needed, every time it runs a machine code instruction.)

Part of the job of translating a high level language program into machine code is managing the mapping of the program's logical variables to the hardware's physical storage.  Since physical storage has constraints, machine code programs must work within them in doing those mappings.

Sometimes a logical variable has to be relocated to alternative physical storage (e.g. from `$a` register to either `$s` register or stack memory).  A machine code instruction (or sequence) is usually required to do such relocation, plus, the compiler or assembly programmer has to be aware that the mapping from variable to storage can be different at different points in the same program.

(Sometimes a logical variable's value is actually in more than one physical storage location, as is the case when manipulating global variables that live in memory and copies are brought into CPU registers to work with.  Similar is true for elements of arrays.)

Comment: You said v,n,i,j should be preserved, why? After calling the swap function, I want to know how the v, n, i, j values ​​are handled in detail.

Comment: The swap function inside sort does not change the value of the register that remembers v n i j , so I thought there was no need to store it in the stack space. If you change the value of the register that remembers j in the swap function, when you return to the for statement after calling the swap function, the changed value of j will interfere with the execution of the loop. I'm thinking that certain values ​​should be preserved only in these cases.

Comment: All 4 of those variables need continuity that spans the `swap` function call.  If `i`'s value is lost by calling `swap` that outer loop won't run properly, right?  So, `i` needs call preserved storage, which could be `$s` registers, or stack memory.  If `i` is mapped only to a `$t` register, that register could be wiped out by `swap`, and that would be disastrous for the `i` variable and hence the outer loop.

Comment: However, I thought that there is no process of directly changing the register value that stores`v` `n` `i` `j` in the code implementing the `swap` function as mips. The swap function is implemented by storing the value of adding a certain constant to the parameter of the swap function in `$t`. Is it necessary to preserve the `v`, `n` , `i`, `j` register values ​​even in this case? (In the body of the article, the code that implements swap as MIPS is inserted.)==============================================
And thank you for your detailed and kind answer to my question.

Comment: Those variables need to survive the function call.  That's all there is to it.  They should use physical storage that supports that.  Since all the registers are accessible for read and write by all machine code, we need to have some consideration regarding the registers.

Comment: Pretend for a second that in a more general case, we don't know how `swap` works: that we cannot see its machine code (and even if we could it might change by its author's bug fix or some such in routine maintenance).  What might `swap` do (or be capable of)?  Wipe out any `$t` or `$a` registers?  Yes, that's allowed by the calling convention.

Comment: Ok, now if you know exactly how `swap` is implemented, you can go non-standard and deconflict register usages between `sort` and `swap`, nothing wrong with that, but that means that if the internal details of `swap` changes, we will have to revisit internal register usage of `sort`

Comment: And because that is a significant maintenance problem in large programs, we advocate the usage of the standard calling convention, which is designed minimizes the coupling requirements between functions to the signature of the functions.  If you use the standard calling convention, then only if you add (or maybe remove) a parameter (change signature) to `swap`, will `sort` have to be revisited.  Build systems are designed to support this, for example, by detecting that file having forward function declarations have changed.

Comment: If a specific function handles values ​​(variables) outside of that function, are you saying that it should be preserved regardless of the function contents? 
Just like in the C language, when you put a variable as a parameter, the parameter value itself is preserved.

Comment: So, if you're trying to learn the MIPS calling convention in the general case, you should assume nothing about `sort` when programming `swap` and vice versa, except their function signatures.

Comment: What do you mean by handling variables outside of the function?  (In a language like C, one function does not have access to another function's variables.  These are concerns of the mapping of logical variables to physical storage, as obviously, two variables cannot occupy the same physical storage at the same time (modulo some very tricky things).

Comment: Like `i` and `j` defined in the sort function, it means a value declared outside the swap() function. (or `v, `n`)

Comment: `swap` does not "handle" variables outside of the itself: from the perspective of logical variables it has no access to `i` or `j` in `sort` at the high level language level.  Only if there is some mistaken physical storage usage can `swap` affect `i` or `j` (and, btw, that is very possible in assembly language, but not in C).